# How can I distill "Expedition to the Barrier Peaks" down to the best 7 or 8 encounters to fit inside one hour?

Tags: published-adventures, gm-preparation

On Friday I'll be doing a role play demo for 13 Montessori students between 12 and 14 years old.  It's a one hour deal, and this is my second time to do it.

Since it is such a short time frame, and such a large group, I'm doing a hugely simplified demo, but this year I am basing it on the old module Expedition to the Barrier Peaks, and I'd like to get your input.

With the limited time frame, I have to try to squeeze in encounters in fairly rapid order.  Last year I was able to do six or seven 'encounters'.  Each encounter was basically them running into a problem of some sort, and then discussing a solution, and rolling a couple of dice to determine the outcome.  I'd like to do something similar, and crib from the Barrier Peaks.

Can you kind people suggest your favorite encounters from the Barrier Peaks?  Which ones would be fun, even in condensed form, for a group of kids?

(edit) ***Q:*** What System, exactly?  ***A:*** No system.  Just something madeup on the fly, like "roll higher than 10 for a success." stuff.  Totally winging it - it's a one hour deal with a dozen kids.  System is like the least of the deal here.

Comment: Related: [The Gamers, Live 2012](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sX4dHkGC1Ig) Would provide a fantastic model for this sort of thing.

Comment: Also related: Microscope and Kingdom by [Ben Robbins](http://arsludi.lamemage.com/) that could be very engaging writ large.

Comment: The question of _"Can you kind people suggest your favorite encounters from the Barrier Peaks?"_ would be very opinion-based, and not make for a good question. Also, is this the [1980 Adventure to the Barrier Peaks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expedition_to_the_Barrier_Peaks) made for OD&D?